# htaccess redirect specific pages to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I’m having some real problems with 301 redirects in my `.htaccess` file.

I have about 20 pages on an old site that I need to redirect to pages on a new site. The URL structure of the new site is totally different.

Here’s one that I tried:

```
Redirect 301 /dan-carr-gear-list/travel-gear https://dancarrphotography.com/gear/travel/
```

Unfortunately, this doesn’t work.

What happens is that you get redirected to `https://dancarrphotography.com/gear/travel-gear/` for some reason.

I just can’t figure it out.

Comment: it seems like you tried Redirect 301 /dan-carr-gear-list/ https://dancarrphotography.com/gear/ before then changed your mind and replace it by this but not clearing browser cache yet , try to clear browser cache then test it again

Comment: OR  this Redirect 301 /dan-carr-gear-list/ dancarrphotography.com/gear is already existing and handled before the mentioned one